# Flutter app crashes after receiving sms when using telephony package

Tags: java, android, flutter, telephony

I have an app that will automatically scan incoming sms. Everything seems to work fine in debug, but in release version of the app, it is crashing when a new sms is received. Here is the stack trace. I am using telephony package and have given all permissions as stated in the telephony package documentation(https://pub.dev/packages/telephony). I have also used `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` before calling background functions.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(22045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(22045): Process: com.example.expense, PID: 22045
E/AndroidRuntime(22045): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.shounakmulay.telephony.sms.IncomingSmsReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String io.flutter.view.FlutterCallbackInformation.callbackLibraryPath' on a null object reference in method 'java.lang.String a1.a$b.toString()'
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4561)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8364)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String io.flutter.view.FlutterCallbackInformation.callbackLibraryPath' on a null object reference in method 'java.lang.String a1.a$b.toString()'
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at a1.a$b.toString(Unknown Source:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3657)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at a1.a.i(Unknown Source:27)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at s0.b.k(Unknown Source:62)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at com.shounakmulay.telephony.sms.IncomingSmsReceiver.b(Unknown Source:30)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at com.shounakmulay.telephony.sms.IncomingSmsReceiver.c(Unknown Source:129)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at com.shounakmulay.telephony.sms.IncomingSmsReceiver.onReceive(Unknown Source:86)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4545)
E/AndroidRuntime(22045):        ... 9 more
```

I used `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` before calling background functions.

Answer (score 0):

Update: It works after downgrading the flutter version. Apparently the latest version of flutter is not friendly with background functions.